# Identify all horror movies in this image?

Tags: character-identification, object-identification

I saw this image on the interwebs, with the caption that there are 40 movies referenced in it. Unfortunately I am so old and incompetent, I was only able to identify Casper the Ghost. Please identify the prop/character and the movie it references.

[image: Color version of an image featuring 40 references to various horror movies]

Here is a number / letter map. Clearly some are referenced more than once, because 37 and e both appear to be the same octopus wearing boxing gloves.

[image: black-and-white version of the same image, with numer labels]

Comment: Oh! "c" is Charlotte's Web, right?

Comment: if you are down-voting because it isn't October yet, the whole year of 2020 is themed Horror.

Comment: I didn't know voting accordingly to the time of the year and the current events was a thing.

Comment: Which number or letter is Casper?

Comment: @NomadMaker #40

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. & A - The villagers coming to attack Frankenstein's castle at the end of [the 1931 film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankenstein_(1931_film)) The villagers are from Frankenstein, the castle itself is Dracula's (according the original artist).
2. The burning [Wicker Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wicker_Man)
3. [IT's balloon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_(novel)).
4. The Headless Horseman from [The Legend of Sleepy Hollow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Sleepy_Hollow).
5. The biohazard symbol from *[28 Days Later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/28_Days_Later)*
6. [Thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thing_(The_Addams_Family)) from *The Addams Family*
7. [Chucky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chucky_(character)) from the *Child's Play* series
8. The death's head moth, as depicted in *[The Silence of the Lambs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Silence_of_the_Lambs_(film))*
9. The house from *The Amityville Horror*
10. The little hanging stick figures from *[The Blair Witch Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blair_Witch_Project)*
11. The Bates Motel is the setting of *Psycho* and the TV prequel *Bates Motel*
12. Father Karras, the titular [Exorcist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Exorcist_(film))
13. [Christine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christine_(novel))
14. Sadako from *[The Ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ring_(franchise))*
15. Likely just a generic tombstone and not a reference to anything
16. A Xenomorph egg from *Alien*
17. According to the artist, the pumpkin is a reference to the *Halloween* series
18. *The Rocky Horror Picture Show*
19. Bandages, those of [The Mummy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mummy_(1932_film))
20. Ghostface from *Scream* (on Mullen Lowe Group's Octopus)
21. The Proton Pack used by the [Ghostbusters](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087332/)
22. The Grudge
23. Annabelle from [The Conjuring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Conjuring) series
24. The *Slaughtered Lamb* pub from *An American Werewolf in London*
25. Wolf Creek
26. The puzzle box from [Hellraiser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellraiser)
27. Mushnik's is the titular shop of [Little Shop of Horrors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Shop_of_Horrors_(film))
28. A participant in *The Purge*
29. *Poltergeist*
30. a red door handle from *The Sixth Sense*
31. The Gremlins emerging from their box
32. *Shaun of the Dead*
33. The tricycle ridden by Danny Torrance in *The Shining*
34. Beetlejuice's suit
35. Freddy Kreuger's outfit from the *Nightmare on Elm Street* films
36. Green Frog Comics from *The Lost Boys*
37. Octopus is the [Mullen Lowe Group's logo](https://www.mullenlowegroup.com/) the creator of the image
38. The Billy puppet from *Saw*
39. Jason Voorhees' hockey mask from the *Friday the 13th* films

<sub>References to the original artists intent come from his own list featured on [this Facebook comment](https://www.facebook.com/MullenLoweGroup/posts/10155741260233389?comment_id=10155762100248389) which is also posted in the [other answer here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/236131/57310).</sub>

Comment: A lot better format with all the additional information, too bad it's not CW, though.

Comment: @TARS considering the additional effort within the same time frame, why would he want this to be a community wiki!

Comment: @Skooba So we don't end up with a bad complete answer and a good incomplete one. But such is the danger with these questions, I guess.

Comment: @TARS ah, but that is what edits are for! Maybe it just personal preference but I'd rather see some take the effort to get most of the way their and earn some rep rather than throw up a quick template and it a be a community wiki from the start. Granted I think there is a meta on that....

Comment: @Skooba That seems about...the single only way to make these questions remotely work, though.

Comment: I gotta get back to work, feel free to edit in any that are wrong or missing, I don't mind.

Comment: One thing I think we can all agree on. This town has a lot of problems.

Comment: "The biohazard symbol from 28 Days Later" - while that may have been the author's intention, it is rather lame to have it as a part of a quiz question. 28 Days Later for sure wasn't the only horror movie to ever prominently feature the common biohazard sign.

Answer (score 6):

The artist has listed the answers [here](https://www.facebook.com/MullenLoweGroup/posts/10155741260233389?comment_id=10155762100248389) on Facebook:

> It's time for us to put you all out of your misery... Are you ready? Here are the answers:
>
> 1. The Pumpkin: Halloween
> 2. Striped suit - Beetle Juice
> 3. Lips - Rocky Horror Picture Show
> 4. Red balloon - IT
> 5. Butterfly on lamp post - Silence of the Lambs
> 6. Tricycle - The Shining
> 7. Hockey mask - Friday the 13th
> 8. Paws in box - Gremlins
> 9. Pack against lamp post - Ghostbusters
> 10. Silhouette under lamp post - The Exorcist
> 11. Hand - The Addams Family
> 12. Castle - Dracula
> 13. Unraveled bandages - The Mummy
> 14. Mushnik's shop - Little Shop of Horrors
> 15. Biohazard sign on chimney - 28 Days Later
> 16. Headless man - Sleepy Hollow
> 17. Burning Statue - Wicker Man
> 18. Green frog comics - The Lost Boys
> 19. Stick symbol on tree - Blair Witch Project
> 20. Striped jumper in window -The Nightmare on Elm Street
> 21. Slaughtered lamb sign - An American Werewolf in London
> 22. Well - The Ring
> 23. Mask with red cheeks - Saw
> 24. Red door knob - The Sixth Sense
> 25. Bates Motel - Psycho
> 26. Mask on our octopus - Scream
> 27. Yellow road sign - Wolf Creek
> 28. Little doll in window - Chucky
> 29. Egg shaped object - Alien
> 30. Hand coming out of ground - Evil Dead
> 31. Cricket bat and shovel - Shaun of the Dead
> 32. Car - Christine
> 33. Mist - The Fog
> 34. Masked man - The Purge
> 35. Spider on tree - Arachnophobia
> 36. Angry mob on hill - Frankenstein
> 37. Girl with hands on TV - Poltergeist
> 38. House in background - The Amityville Horror
> 39. Box in window - Hellraiser
> 40. Doll on rocking chair - The Conjuring

Comment: Just that the numbers don't match to the question in any way.

Comment: @TARS - I suppose I could put them into the correct order, but the quote is *a quote*.

Comment: Seems like the tombstone is just a side decoration?

Comment: A user wanted to edit this answer to point out that that name of the doll from _The Conjuring_ is Annabelle. For the record, that is the doll's name, but since this is a direct quote from the artist, it shouldn't be altered. With one or two exceptions (such as Chucky), the artist apparently chose to specify the _films_ these items or characters were from, rather than naming the items or characters themselves.

Answer (score -1):

#6 is a hand from the movie called "The Hand" from 1981 where a hand that was cut off goes around and chokes people.  Neither "Thing" or "The Addams Family are horror films.  Course there is a Horror film called "The Thing" but it has nothing to do with "Thing"

Comment: Since the artist has stated that it's Thing from the Addams Family ("*Hand - The Addams Family*") , I'm really not sure where you're getting this from

Comment: There are also lone disembodied hands committing acts of violence in _And then the screaming starts_ and _Vault of horror_.

Answer (score -2):

There are 40 film references in this picture.

The mist, headstone and cross are generic horror items not in reference to any films, and the boxing octopus is the logo of the company who created the image.

A Nightmare on Elm Street

Alien

An American Werewolf in London

Arachnophobia

Beetlejuice

Poltergeist

Little Shop of Horrors

Child's Play

Christine

Dracula

Frankenstein

Friday the 13th

Ghostbusters

Gremlins

Halloween

Hellraiser

IT

Poltergeist

Psycho

Saw

Scream

Shaun of the Dead

Sleepy Hollow

The Silence of the Lambs

The Addams Family

The Amityville Horror

The Blair Witch Project

The Conjuring

The Evil Dead

The Exorcist

The Lost Boys

The Mummy

The Purge

The Ring

The Rocky Horror Picture Show

The Shining

The Sixth Sense

The Wickerman

28 Days Later

Wolf Creek

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This question already has 2 high-quality answers, one by the creator, and the other which identifies _which_ element is associated to a particular movie.  This answer doesn't seem to provide nearly as much value; you should try to add new answers only when you have substantial information to give that's not already covered.  You might want to take the [tour].